# Adding a Link to a Field in a Field Set?

Tags: apex, visualforce

[image]

```
String queryFields = null;
             for(Schema.FieldSetMember field : SObjectType.Task.FieldSets.Activity_Detail_Page.getFields()){

                queryFields = (queryFields == null ? field.getFieldPath() : queryFields+', '+field.getFieldPath());

             } 

             String query = 'Select '+queryFields+' from Task where Id=\''+activityId+'\'';

             task = Database.query(query);
```

i'll creating a field-set,now how do i add link on any field?

above code is  for dynamically query creation . below code of page

```
 <apex:pageBlock title="Activity" id="Block1">
      <apex:pageBlockSection title="Activity Detail">
        <apex:repeat value="{!$ObjectType.Task.FieldSets.Activity_Detail_Page}" var="field">
            <apex:outputField value="{!Task[field.fieldPath]}" />
        </apex:repeat>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

As per the image attached, I want to add a link in **Rounded field** that liks to **account**. Can any one help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this below code I hope this is helpful to you.

```
<apex:pageBlock title="Opportunity" id="Block1">
      <apex:pageBlockSection title="Opportunity Detail">
      <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
        Account Name
        <apex:outputLink value="/apex/AccountDetail?accountId={!aId}&UserId={!userId}&contactIds={!contactIds}">
            <apex:outputfield value="{!Opportunity.Account.Name}" />
        </apex:outputLink>
        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
        <apex:repeat value="{!$ObjectType.Opportunity.FieldSets.Opportunity_Detail_Page}" var="field">
            <apex:outputField value="{!Opportunity[field.fieldPath]}" />
        </apex:repeat>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like a formula field that spits out a link to that record would work. To do this, first make a text formula field, then use the following method:

```
HYPERLINK(url, friendly_name [, target])
```

Where url is the id and friendly name is what you want shown to the use. The target is optional and is used to say whether or not you want to open in a new tab/window or not. See [the docs on HYPERLINK](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_functions_a_h.htm&language=en_US#HYPERLINK)  for more info.

Comment: didn't get you !!! any example

Comment: Added some code and a description. Hope that helps